# Are there any way to extract unique signatures from SQL server 2014 trace file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trace, sql-server-profiler, sql-server-performance

I am capturing tuning trace via SQL server 2014 profiler

Since my game is pretty active the file gets GBs in few minutes

However there are so many duplicate queries

So i want to extract unique signatures out of it

So my question is how can i do it ?

Are there any tools etc ?

Ty very much for answers

Comment: You might want to consider applying better filters. GBs of query data in a few minutes? Are you really going to analyze all those queries? Why don't you start with a filter on duration or reads, so that you're focusing on queries that are actually potential targets for optimization? Anyway check out [ClearTrace](http://www.scalesql.com/cleartrace/) and [Qure Analyzer](http://www.dbsophic.com/qure-analyzer).

Comment: If you're interested in aggregate stats about queries, you could investigate the dynamic management views. Maybe start with `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx